# Create a NSIS installer shortcut for a Java JAR file with a space in the path?

Tags: nsis

I use NSIS installer to create simple script to install a Java JAR file and create a desktop link in Windows to execute the JAR file. The user selects the install directory (including location of the JAR file which can include a SPACE in the path).

However, how can I escape or place the JAR file location in quotes using a NSIS script depending on the user's install directory?

For example--the desktop link might need to be:

```
C:\Windows\system32\java.exe -jar "D:\Me\Test PPP Install\PPP_Winx64_1.jar"
```

(Note the quotes are needed so the -jar parameter is properly handled by Java.)

In my NSIS script I use something like:

```
 createShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}.lnk" "java" " -jar $INSTDIR\${PPPJAR}" "$INSTDIR\${PPPICON}"
```

(This creates the link with the additional icon attribute.)

I tried escaping the quotes in

```
"\" -jar $INSTDIR\${PPPJAR}\""
```

and

```
"" -jar $INSTDIR\${PPPJAR}""
```

and

```
" -jar $\"$INSTDIR\${PPPJAR}$\""
```

and

```
' -jar "$INSTDIR\${PPPJAR}$"'
```

but none works--the NSIS compiler either fails, first two, or the resulting shotcut omits the needed quotes (last items).

I have searched for other samples but all use non-space paths--but this is not practical as the user needs to be able to specify the install directory.

Thus, how can I get the path attribute for the JAR file to be in quotes using a NSIS script?

Answer (score 2):

NSIS has 3 quote characters so having to use `$\"` to escape is usually not necessary.

`CreateShortcut "$desktop\foo.lnk" "$instdir\foo.exe" '-bar "c:\hello world"'` should work...

Answer (score 0):

The escape tips at [Passing arguments to java vm from NSIS script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562915/passing-arguments-to-java-vm-frocm-nsis-script) DO work.

```
" -jar $\"$INSTDIR\${PPPJAR}$\"" DOES work.
```

(The error was my own. During testing, I create a Start Menu Shortcut an a Desktop Shortcut. Unfortunately, I was testing the desktop which did not have the escape sequence. Dumb in retrospect.)

The NSIS space escapes work:

using '" to escape or "" or $\" .  But not that I needed to place the escaped quotes just around the JAR file path--not the entire passed attribute.